# Email Send Based on Rollup summary Sum

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning, email

In the Order object, I have two fields one is Order Count(Rollup Summary) and another one is Total order, My external system sends Order with Total Order and line item.

I need to send email to users whenever Order Count and Total Order is a mismatch. My Order is getting created first and then the Order product rolls up to Order.
So initially my both Order Count and Total Order can be the same or different but it won't give a clear idea.
Within 5 mins of my Order creation, order line items will also be created.

How do I send an email which is similar to real-time. I don't mind a delay of 10 or 15 mins.
Any Idea would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: do all the line items for an order come in a single transaction? Or do they dribble in over multiple transactions. If the latter, it is hard to know when the last line item was sent/received

Comment: That I'm not sure, but I hope they come in single transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a rollup, you can't trigger it from the order. You would have to do this from the related item.

You can use a flow that runs when an item is created or [deleted](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_trigger_flow.htm&type=5&release=228). When this happens, you can query the order record and its related records and literally count how many items are retrieved, and check this number against your order record's field.

Then it is a matter of creating a condition in your flow to send an email message to whoever you want to.